# Strange comma appending issue with @ModelAttribute

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

Platform: Spring 3.1.2, Tomcat 7.0.30

The issue started after upgraded to Spring 3.1 from 3.0

I have a normal spring enabled form as:

> ```
> <c:url value='/healthcare/insurance/policy/save' var="url" />
> <form:form commandName="insurancePolicy" action="${url }" method="POST" cssClass="form-horizontal">
>   <div class="module">
>       <div class="header">
>           <strong><spring:message code="insurance.policy.view.formbox" /> </strong>
>       </div>
>       <div class="module-content row-fluid">
>           <div class="span4">
>
>               <div class="control-group">
>                   <label class="control-label"><spring:message code="insurance.policy.view.policyId" /></label>
>                   <div class="controls">
>                       <form:input path="policyId" cssClass="span10" readonly="true" />
>                   </div>
>               </div>
>
>               <div class="control-group">
>                   <label class="control-label"><spring:message code="insurance.policy.view.tpaId" /></label>
>                   <div class="controls">
>                       <form:select path="tpaId" items="${tpas }" itemLabel="tpaName" itemValue="tpaId" cssClass="span10" />
>                   </div>
>               </div>
> ```

And so on.

The way I submit is:

```
function save(){
    $("#insurancePolicy").submit();

}
```

The way I catch is through the Controller which resides in an abstracted class as below:

```
public abstract class AbstractCrudViewController<T, PK extends Number, META extends T> extends AbstractViewController {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected String save(@ModelAttribute T t, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

        logger.debug("Executing save for model: {}", t.toString());

        try{

            if (getPrimaryKeyValue(t) == null || ((Number) getPrimaryKeyValue(t)).intValue() <=0 ){
                logger.debug("Creating new record");
                PK pk =  getCrudService().create(t);
                logger.debug("New record created with ID: {}", pk);
                ViewUtil.addSuccess(model, "crud.saveSuccess", request, getPrimaryKeyValue(t));

            }
```

The init binder is declared in the AbstractViewController as:

```
public abstract class AbstractViewController {

     @InitBinder
     public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";       
        binder.registerCustomEditor(DateTime.class, new DateTimeEditor(dateFormat,true));
     }

}
```

OK. Now the problem is: I'm saving form and the log says:

```
DEBUG:com.keype.hawk.hr.mvc.StaffViewController[save]:Executing save for model: Staff [staffId=null, firstName=Steve,, lastName=Harris,, middleName=,, nationality=AF, dob=2012-09-11T00:00:00.000+03:00, status=1000, title=Mr, address1=, address2=, city=, state=, postalCode=, country=AF, homePhoneAreaCode=, homePhone=,, homePhoneExt=, homePhoneAllowSoliciation=, workPhoneAreaCode=, workPhone=null, workPhoneExt=, workPhoneAllowSoliciation=, fax=, mobileAreaCode=, mobile=, mobileAllowSolicitation=, email=null, joiningDate=null, gender=, govtId=, maritalStatus=, passportNumber=, passportExpiryDate=null, totalWorkExperience=, notes=, staffCreated=null, staffModified=null, dateCreated=null, dateModified=null]
```

Notice the comma after each field.

For debugging, I serialized the form using jquery serialize and checked and there NO comma with it. Then ajax-posted this data to the server and after @ModelAttribute did it's job, The comma gets appended.

Any idea? Something with Init binder?

Comment: I think commas are only `toString()` representation of data, what is the problem here? What does not work?

Comment: firstName=Steve,,    -- See two commas. One is the problem another one is the toString() related.

Comment: The problem is an additional comma gets appended with each field which is not user supplied

Comment: As Xaerxess said - the logging is just showing the `toString()` output from your class that is being bound (entering via the generic T). Look at the source of that class for details. The multiple commas simply indicate that one of the fields is empty (the `toString()` implementation will make it clear).

Comment: Thanks, but toString() is not the problem. Even to database the values are saved pushed with a comma. The issue is certainly somewhere between the form gets POST submitted and spring mvc do the binding. I also check the POST variables via firebug Net tool and till there the comma is not present.  Anyway, the tostring() looks very normal: @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "InsurancePolicy [policyId=" + policyId + ", tpaId=" + tpaId
    + ", policyCode=" + policyCode + ", companyCode=" + companyCode...

Comment: If the String has comma in the data already then how to handle this situation. Can it be a custom delimiter? If so how to set the custom delimiter?

Answer (score 25):

I was experiencing the same issue, but Twitter Bootstrap wasn't the cause.

In my case, we had 2 inputs having the same name attribute. In that case, data for this two input are sent as an Array. Since my inputs were empty, the array was `myName=,`

Comment: Yes in my case issue was due to duplicate fields, 2 fields with same `path`

Comment: I also had this issue and mine was because I had copied the input field for a "confirm" field and changed the id attribute but not the name attribute, so two fields with the same name attribute.

Comment: Can confirm it's a duplicate path fields that I'm using in my Spring Form tags. It also hinted to me that I should redesign the layouts of my JSPs, so I rely less on the Spring Forms.